# Difference Between Armature and Bone Layers?

Tags: animation, armature, interface, add-on, system

So I'm programming a little customized add-on and want to implement a button to change the layer of bones in armature and pose mode.

But there are two different layer types, to armature and bone layer. I didn't find something, so could someone explain me the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...You could be referring to a few things, but I'm just going to run through all of them real quick.

*Armature Scene Layer*: The layer in which the armature is in the scene.  This matters for rendering and viewport filtering.

*Armature Layers*: The Bone Layers in an Armature.  Activating a Layer makes it visible in the editor.

*Armature Protected Layers*: Runs parallel to the Armature layers, activating this layer makes the corresponding Armature Layer write-protected.  Users will be unable to edit bones that are in this layer.

*Bone layers*: Armature Layers from the perspective of bones.  Determines which armature layer(s) a bone resides in.

Comment: Thanks, I think that was already deep enogh! So, when I want to organize my bones in one single armature display only the bones I work with in the moment, I should choose the Bone Layer command. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you would assign your bones to a bone layer, then choose that layer to be active in the Armature layer.

Comment: So just in the moment I saw that I made an error in my ceode. Because I (befor that question) build a menu with the armature layer command. Now I used it and, just like youre description says, instead of move the bones to layer 3, I only saw the empty layer 3... Thanks!